# How to optimize pgplsql function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have function which is triggered for each row. It has next statements:

```
SELECT DocDate
  FROM Operation
  WHERE Operation.ID = New.OperationID
  INTO _DocDate;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE ChangeSaldo( _DocDate, ... );
```

Each row belongs to parent table `Operation` where we fetch `DocDate`.
We need run `ChangeSaldo` for each row with its own `_DocDate`
That is guaranteed that all rows belongs to same row in `Operation` table

Will Postgres execute this `SELECT` for each row or this statement will be cached?
If it is not cached is there a way to optimize `SELECT` so it will be executed only once?

Comment: do you want to run function `ChangeSaldo` against each `DocDate` value in your `select`?.. Please rephrase

Comment: @VaoTsun   Done. Rephrased

Comment: If you think that repeatedly running that SELECT is a waste, with reason, maybe that logic shouldn't be in a trigger in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I plan to create `stable` function and put there that `SELECT`.
Because of nature of `stable` functions the result will be cached

Comment: later I will extend answer with function example after I implement it